# Assign custom function return value and use in loop

Tags: php, smarty

I'm using the **CodeIgniter** framework with **Smarty** and use a custom Smarty function which returns config items:

```
{ci_config name='sitemap'}
```

This call **returns an multidimensional array** containing the websites sitemap:

```
$config['sitemap'] = array('dashboard' => array('uri'=>'dashboard',
                                                'title'=>'Dashboard'),
                           'photos' => array('uri'=>'photos',
                                             'title'=>'Photos'));
```

*Note: this is an example array, the actual array will be really multilevel*

I would like to **loop this array** but how do I **use the return value in a loop** construct?

Although wrong, this is what i would like to achieve:

```
{foreach {ci_config name='sitemap'} as $node} 

<p>{$node.uri}</p> 

{/foreach}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

*Note: I'm using the latest Smarty 3 RC2.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User 'mohrt' from the Smarty forum posted following good anwser:

```
{ci_config name="sitemap" assign="map"} 
{foreach $map as $node} 

<p>{$node.uri}</p> 

{/foreach}
```

> also make sure your ci_config plugin
>   supports the assign attribute

http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?t=17655

Just make sure to assign the variable in your custom function or plugin with the Smarty instance.

Thanks mohrt!

Answer (score 0):

use section to loop through the array instead of foreach. There should be examples in the documentation to help you deal with the looping issue.
http://www.smarty.net/manual/en/language.function.section.php

Comment: yes, but the looping itself is not the problem, it's how to capture the return value of the custom function and use that in a smarty construct...

Comment: ow and also, section is decrecated in Smarty 3. thanks though ;-)